# Popup window with information on mouse over hyperlink

Tags: php, jquery, popup, modal-dialog

I want to display contact info with the link to contact us page on mouse over hyperlink just like stackoverflow (mouse over user name) and gmail (click over user name). The below is what the latest updated code looks like.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/start/jquery-ui.css" />

<script>
$('#open').mouseenter(function() {
    $('#dialog_content').dialog('open');
});
$('#dialog_content').mouseleave(function() {
    $('#dialog_content').dialog('close');
});
var posX = $('#open').offset().left;
var posY = $('#open').offset().top;
console.log(posX,posY);
$('#dialog_content').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    open: function() {
        closedialog = 1;
        $(document).bind('click', overlayclickclose);
    },
    focus: function() {
        closedialog = 0;
    },
    close: function() {
        $(document).unbind('click');
    },
    buttons: {
      /*  
      Ok: function() {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
        */
     },
    show: {
            effect: 'fade',
            duration: 800
        },
    hide: {
            effect: 'fade',
            duration: 800
        },

    position: [posX,posY+25],
    resizable: false
});
</script>
<style>
.ui-dialog-titlebar {display:none;}
#other_content {width:200px; height:200px;background-color:grey;}
#dialog_content{display:none;}
</style>
<div id="dialog_content">bla bla bla</div>




<div id="open">CONTACT US</div>
```

The error that i get

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'left' of undefined

Comment: Post the code you have and we can help you from there. At least the modal you are using so we can help using it.

Comment: updated the question with the code.

Comment: can't see the code...

Comment: updated...please check

Comment: Check this and take some ideas: http://jsfiddle.net/T7YSJ/

Comment: I want the window to remain static till the time user click some where outside the window. In your example the info box goes away as soon as the mouse is removed from hyperlink.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this option:

[jsfiddle.net/3mxGM/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/3mxGM/4/)

It creates a jQuery modal window with the info inside the div with id `dialog_content`. You might want dynamic content inside that div from your database or something. Anyway this should work for what you want.

html:

```
<div id="dialog_content">
Here you can write the info to show up in the modal window.<br /><br />
If you know what AJAX is, could be a good idea to use it to query your database and get the info from there.</div>
<a href="#" id="open">Open dialog</a>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#open').mouseenter(function() {
$('#dialog_content').dialog('open');
});
$('#dialog_content').mouseleave(function() {
$('#dialog_content').dialog('close');
});
var posX = $('#open').offset().left;
var posY = $('#open').offset().top;
$('#dialog_content').dialog({
autoOpen: false,
focus: function() {
    closedialog = 0;
},
close: function() {
    $(document).unbind('click');
},
buttons: {
  /*  
  Ok: function() {
        $(this).dialog('close');
    }
    */
 },
show: {
        effect: 'fade',
        duration: 800
    },
hide: {
        effect: 'fade',
        duration: 800
    },
position: [posX,posY+25],
resizable: false
});
});
```

css:

```
.ui-dialog-titlebar {display:none;}
```

Comment: thanks for the code. I want the dialog box to be static ie user should not be able to move it. Secondly i dont want it to be expandable and also to header. It should be a simple div with light borders. The code you have given is for jquery dialog

Comment: if you can mouse over username in stack overflow site you will get a popup window. I am looking out for some thing like that.

Comment: is it static content ore dynamic you want inside? as big as stackoverflow's?

Comment: dynamic wrt contents inside that window. Yes as big as stackoverflow's

Comment: also that should be sticking to the hyperlink and not at the center of the window.

Comment: If you want dynamic content in it you need a dialog. If its simple border and draggable or not, that is CSS and small ajustments. You need dialog to be able to add content to your info window.

Comment: this looks fine the only thing is i don't want it to be resized(the size of popup should remain constant). If you can please update. Also is there any way to open it on mouse over?

Comment: also if the window can disappear once the mouse is removed from the popup window just like stack overflow...

Comment: Thats what I wanted. Can I have that fading effect at the time it appears and disappears. Also some delay before it closes. Thanks in advance!

Comment: the position of the pop up window is according to the parent window ie [0,0]. How can i get it to be according to hyperlink. ie where ever I place the link the window should open just below the link.

Comment: these are the 2 positions x and y axis according to the code. var posX = $('#open').offset().left;
var posY = $('#open').offset().top; the popup currently opening a bit far away from the link cant it be brought closer or cant i set the coordinates according to the hyperlink?

Comment: This does what you want, the problem was the "dialog_content" div needed to be `display:none;`. Check here:http://jsfiddle.net/3mxGM/12/

Comment: yes this is better but again the popup window is overlapping the hyperlink cant it open somewhere just below it?

Comment: some thing like this position: [posX,posY+25], but i dont know if its a right approach...also i observed that it does not close on its own some time can I have a close link inside the popup so that the user can close it, if the user wishes to..

Comment: About the position do as you wrote: posY +... If you want a close button just add a link and the target can be `$('#dialog_content').dialog('close');`

Comment: You are loading jQuery 10, I tried that and it works here: http://jsfiddle.net/3JLjL/

Comment: no i tried it on my web page its not working. I have updated the entire code in my initial post. I don't know how is it working with fiddle!

Comment: the link to my webpage goo.gl/TrznR

Comment: ok, I got it. In the fiddle the script is run `onload`. 1 min and I repost

Comment: Try now, you need to add `$(document).ready(function(){ ... });` around your code. Otherwise he look for the div with id #open and it doesn't exist yet. Like this he will only run the script when the page has loaded.

Comment: where exactly do i have to add these lines can you update your code above so that i can get some ideas

Comment: I did already, check in the answer. first line is `$(document).ready(function(){` then the old code. The last line is `});`

Comment: I see it works now, Good. In my answer I also removed the code for a old idea we tried with `overlayclickclose`. So take the code from my answer. And give me back the answer credit haha :)

Comment: whats this error now Uncaught ReferenceError: overlayclickclose is not defined

Comment: just answered you in my last comment.

Comment: ya sorry i did not see your code. Last thing tell me please if at all i want it on click event what changes do I need to make.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I indeed troubled you a lot....;) but you were of a great help for me...

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a much more code-simple popup tooltip, I am enjoying a customized version of this:

http://devseo.co.uk/examples/pure-css-tooltips/#

If this is too fancy for you it was just some css3 transitions on top of this more basic version, explained well here:

http://sixrevisions.com/css/css-only-tooltips/

Comment: I want the window to remain static till the time user click some where outside the window. Just like stack overflow when some one mouse overs the hyperlink the window opens.